# Inconsistant behavior when re-linking missing textures. sRGB and Non-Color mismatches

Tags: texturing, linked-data, packed-data

I am having some trouble when re-linking image textures that have single user copies using different color spaces. I.E. A texture being used multiple times in the file, both in Non-Color and sRGB color spaces:

[image]
[image]

1. Create two objects and assign a unique material to them.
2. Plug in the same image texture into the base color of each object, but make one of them a single user copy set to "Non-Color" instead of "sRGB".
3. Rename the texture on disk to something different to break the links.
4. Point your materials to the new texture on disk.
5. Notice that your single user copy **is no longer a single user copy.** If you change the color space to non-color, the other material will change too.
6. This can be mitigated in simple scenes by making another single user copy. But if this material is used all over it can quickly become a nightmare trying to remember what was supposed to be sRGB and what was supposed to be non-color.

I can provide more images if any of this is confusing.

Is this working as intended? Or is this a bug? If I make a single user copy, I expect that datablock to function independently from the copy. But the process of re-linking the texture breaks this.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). Not sure I understand. How exactly do you "*4. Point your materials to the new texture*"? I don't think Blender can directly replace a missing image with a different one.

Comment: Hi! Just click on the small folder icon: https://i.imgur.com/PjVJbdG.png

Comment: Oh, ok :). 'Single user' is assigned to the image texture, so when you load a new one, Blender doesn't know it's supposed to be a single user copy. But you can get there using *RMB > Remap* in the Outliner. I can post a full answer when I get home :).

Comment: That would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When opening a new texture, Blender doesn't know it's meant to be a single user copy.
You should *Remap* the old texture instead, so it'll change for all materials at once.

1. Add your 'new texture.jpg', with a second copy (new texture.001) for the non-color variant
2. Open *Outliner > Scene*
3. Right click the 'old texture.jpg' and go *> Remap users > 'new texture.jpg' > OK*.

[image]